# use parameters passed through bottle routes in my SQL SELECT statement

Tags: python, mysql, bottle

What is the correct syntax to use parameters passed through bottle routes in a SQL statement?  (tons of code omitted for clarity here, everything works except this)

```
@route('/sqldynamic/<foo>/<bar>')
def sqlDyanmic(foo, bar):

        db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","username","password","database" )
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT this, that WHERE this > foo AND that like '%bar%';")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return str(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT this, that WHERE this > %s AND that like %s;", (foo, bar))
```

(This is irrespective of Bottle.)

(Also, if you care about SQL injection then you should add some validation.)